# Ruby - How to output "#{}" in a string?

Tags: ruby, string

Ruby uses the following characters `#{}` for string interpolation. If, for some reason, I would like to output those characters in a string, how would I do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use single quote:

```
puts '#{}'
```

Or if you want to use double quote, then escape it.

```
puts "\#{some_var} will be #{some_var}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Single quotation will of course work, but what if you want to include them in string too and don't want to escape anything inside it? Use custom delimiter like that:

```
2.0.0p353 :001 > %q['"#{foo}[f]] #or e.g. %q&'"#{foo}[f]& 
 => "'\"\#{foo}[f]"
```

%q is the equivalent of single quotes and %Q is for double quotes.

Comment: Well, as for `%q[]` or even `%Q[]` you must escape closing delimiter if it is not in pair with opening delimiter: `%q[somewords]]` will raise an error.

Comment: That's true, that's why you could use other delimiter then.

Comment: I mean your question suggest that `%q[]` allow user to type *anything* without escaping.

Comment: Oh, do that w'd be of course wrong, that's why I've written that small q replaces single quote and Q is like double quote.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose `#{}` in single quotes. Any string interpolation is not performed inside single quotes. Or, otherwise, you can escape the given characters, like this: `\#{}`.

Examples:

```
⚡  pry                                                                                +next: 2 | total: 22 | ▸▸▸▸▹▹▹▹▹▹
[1] pry(main)> var = 3
=> 3
[2] pry(main)> puts '#{var}';
#{var}
[3] pry(main)> puts "#{var}";
3
[4] pry(main)> puts "\#{var}";
#{var}
[5] pry(main)> '#{var}'
=> "\#{var}"
[6] pry(main)> "#{var}"
=> "3"
[7] pry(main)> "\#{var}"
=> "\#{var}"
[8] pry(main)>
```